# Swift: Passing a class method as a function parameter (instead of a generic function)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, function-parameter

I'm trying to call a function on a root view controller from a popover view controller.  The function below works but it seems there should be a better way:

```
func doSomethingInRoot() {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let currentRoot = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? RootViewController {
            currentRoot.somefunction()
    }
}
```

In the above code, `doSomethingInRoot` would be contained in the popover, and `someFunction` would be a function of `RootViewController`.

What I'm looking for is a way to pass `someFunction` to another function that contains the `if let` above, however, the problem is `currentRoot` is only assigned as a `RootViewController` within the above (i.e., `doSomethingInRoot` doesn't know that it's being passed a method of `RootViewController` instead of a generic function).

In writing this question, I realized that I could do the following, which feels pretty clean, but I'm still curious whether I can pass a method to a specific class as parameter.

```
func doSomethingInRoot() {
    if let root = getRoot() {
        root.someFunction()
    }
}

func getRoot() -> RootViewController? {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let currentRoot = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? RootViewController {
        return currentRoot
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: btw getRoot can just be implemented as `return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController as? RootViewController`. It's also preferable to us a computed property over a function for soemthing like this

Comment: Check out delegation pattern

Answer (score 1):

In your popover view controller, you could add a property like this to hold the reference to someFunction

```
var rootsSomeFunction: (()->Void)!
```

Then assign the reference when creating the popover VC whether it's in `prepareForSegue`, or after you instantiate if from storyboard...etc. I'd also move `getRoot()` to the App Delegate.

```
popoverVC.rootsSomeFunction = appDelegate.getRoot().someFunction().self
```

Finally, in your popover view controller, you can call it by the property like this:

```
self.rootsSomeFunction()
```